# AS3: Camera-Drag is jerking

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air, drag

I have a big problem because I need to move my camera by dragging the mouse (finger on mobile) to a position you want.

The code itself works fine but I have a bad jerking while dragging.

My Code:

```
if(_drag)
        {
            var mousePos:Point = new Point(_gameRef._stage.mouseX, _gameRef._stage.mouseY);
            var localPos:Point = _gameRef.MainElement.globalToLocal(mousePos);

            var diffX:Number = MathHelper.Difference(_prevMPosX, localPos.x);
            var diffY:Number = MathHelper.Difference(_prevMPosY, localPos.y);

            // Add the position changes for the camera
            if(localPos.x < _prevMPosX)
                _gameRef.CamController.x += diffX;
            if(localPos.x > _prevMPosX)
                _gameRef.CamController.x -= diffX;
            if(localPos.y < _prevMPosY)
                _gameRef.CamController.y += diffY;
            if(localPos.y > _prevMPosY)
                _gameRef.CamController.y -= diffY;

            // change the previous mouse position to the current
           _prevMPosX = localPos.x;
           _prevMPosY = localPos.y;

            e.updateAfterEvent();
        }
```

The funny thing is that when I change the + to - and opposite then it works without jerking (but it doesn't feel natural so it's not the solution to my problem).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, the fault was to use the local coordinates.

No I've made every dependency from my global stage coordinates and it works without any jerking!